# Run specific code within a function only once

Tags: c#

```
public static void Order_go(string url, string name) 
{
    // I want to run the line below only once
    var driver = new ChromeDriver(); 

    driver.Url = (url);  
    IWebElement b_login1 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login"));
    b_login1.SendKeys("aa");
    IWebElement b_pass1 = driver.FindElement(By.Name("managerPw"));
    b_pass1.SendKeys("123");

    // Execute each time when it is called
}
```

I tried

```
Boolean once = true;
if (once)
{
    var driver = new ChromeDriver();
    once = false;
}
```

However, when I call this function, the value of `once` becomes `true` again.
How can I run  this code only once?

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: make it a global variable?

Comment: @DanielA.White Right, I see. my terminology is not on point there but when I say "global variable" I meant creating a variable to the _containing class_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `driver` a `static` member of your class. Check it for `null`.

```
static ChromeDriver driver;
public static void Order_go(string url, string name) 
{
     if (driver == null) { driver = new ChromeDriver(); }

     driver.Url = (url);  
     IWebElement b_login1 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login"));
     b_login1.SendKeys("aa");
     IWebElement b_pass1 = driver.FindElement(By.Name("managerPw"));
     b_pass1.SendKeys("123");
     //Execute each time when it is called
}
```

I would caution you that `ChromeDriver` may not be thread safe.

Comment: why not just `static ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` within the containing class?

Comment: Would `Lazy` be an option?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest initialising it globally within the containing class (sorry if the terminology is not correct in C#).

```
static ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

public static void Order_go(string url, string name) 
{
     driver.Url = (url);  
     IWebElement b_login1 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login"));
     b_login1.SendKeys("aa");
     IWebElement b_pass1 = driver.FindElement(By.Name("managerPw"));
     b_pass1.SendKeys("123");
     //Execute each time when it is called
}
```

Comment: When an instance of the class is created here it will initialize the field with value even in case when there are no invocations of `Order_go`

Comment: @Fabjan I know that. the OP didn't mention anything about avoiding to initiate the `ChromeDriver` object when `Order_go` is not expected to be invoked.  also why create an object of the containing class if you're not going to call the `Order_go` method (assuming it's the only method in the class)?

Comment: @Fabjan if that would be a concern, private static variable and a static property should be used.